# Communication between two subnets

Tags: networking

I have a simple network described below:

```
Server1 (Two NICs):  
eth0: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Public IP address connected to ISP device  
eth1: 192.168.0.1 LAN1(192.168.0.0)

Server2 (Two NICs):  
eth0: 192.168.0.3   
eth2: 192.168.1.1 LAN2(192.168.1.0)
```

What I would like to do is to communicate machines from LAN1 with machines from LAN2.

My Linux knowledge is rather poor, so hope anyone can help me in this matter.

Below I put the output of **ip addr** and **ip route** of both servers
**Server1**
***ip addr***

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:ae:52:cc:13:69 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xx.xx.xx.xxx/30 brd xx.xx.xx.xxx scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::d6ae:52ff:fecc:1369/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:ae:52:cc:13:6a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::d6ae:52ff:fecc:136a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

***ip route***

```
default via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev eth0  metric 100
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/30 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.1
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.3 dev eth1
```

where:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is my ISP Gateway
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/30 is my subnet
zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz is my public IP address
(but it doesn't matter in this case)

**Server2**
***ip addr***

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:54:c0:43:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.3/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::223:54ff:fec0:439e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether ec:08:6b:06:3f:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth2
    inet6 fe80::ee08:6bff:fe06:3fdd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

***ip route***

```
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.3
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  metric 100
```

**EDIT:**
I put the output of `traceroute` command from **Server1**. Maybe it helps:
`traceroute to 192.168.1.14 (192.168.1.14), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3)  0.102 ms  0.092 ms  0.084 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  *^C`

The topology of network looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P89Hg.png).

Comment: Are these servers running on Ubuntu? Also, it seems you have `eth1` on **server1** and `eth0` on **server2** as the same assuming they are on same subnet. You should ideally have access to.

Comment: Yes, both of them are running on ubuntu and are on the same subnet as You said. What I have done so far is to add route on **server1** to communicate with LAN2 via 192.168.0.3, but the only IP address I can ping from server1 is 192.168.1.1. I cannot PING other hosts in **LAN2**

Comment: I'm really confused now. You would need to add more information on the interface including routes, gateways... etc. that you have added. Otherwise, its nearly difficult to predict.

Comment: I posted an answer, which maybe helps you. But as @AzkerM pointed out, we need a lot more information about your configuration otherwise it's just shooting in the woods. Please add the output of `ip addr` and `ip route` of server2, as you said yourself you added a route.

Comment: Ok. Thank all of you so far. I am out right now. I will describe it more precicely in the evening

Comment: Ok, i put some more details. Maybe it will be helpful. If anyone can check, i will appreciate this

Comment: Has anyone any idea? Please!

Comment: For me it looks like you should be able to ping from server1 to server2 because you added the route from one network into the other and you said ip-forwarding is enabled. Have you tried adding an interface to the ping command on server1? `ping -I eth1 192.168.0.3` Please add step-by-step what you have done so far. Maybe that will help us.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand You. I can ping from server1 to server2 using both IPs (192.168.0.3 and 192.168.1.1), but I can't ping other hosts in 192.168.1.0 subnet. If I traceroute host in 192.168.1.0 subnet I can reach 192.168.0.3 and then it stop.   I will update my question putting output from traceroute command. I will draw the topology of my network as well.

Comment: What is the default gateway of the computers on the `192.168.1.0/24` network? Do they point at `192.168.1.1`? From `192.168.1.14` can you ping `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.0.3`?

Comment: @stevieb That was the problem. Thomas pointed this out in the comment  below the answer, so I checked it and realized it was set incorrectly. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The **key-word** is `ip-forwarding`

To enable IPv4-forwarding on Server2, I think that is what you want to do, first check if it is enabled:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
```

If it has the value `0` it's disabled (default).

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Enables it, but only for your current session (until reboot).

If you want to make this configuration permanent the best way to do it is using the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` where you can add a line containing

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

To enable the changes in that file, use:

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

---

**Before you just copy commands, please try to understand them**

Comment: I've checked and it was enabled already. I updated my question putting some more details. Please take a look if you can.

Comment: What about the route back from the host with IP 192.168.1.14? Does this host have a default gateway? If yes, which one?

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. That was the problem. Devices in the 192.168.1.0 subnet are IP cameras and video recorder installed by other company. Despite the fact that I told them how it has to be configured, they set one of the switches as default gateway. Thanks to your suggestion I've checked it.